# S3 Presigned Urls with IAM Role on EC2 not working - GET

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, pre-signed-url

I have an ec2 instance with nodejs and aws sdk. I have an IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance which includes: EC2 Full Access, S3 Full Access and a few other things.

Here's how I instantiate the S3 service:

```
const config:  S3.Types.ClientConfiguration = {
    apiVersion: "2006-03-01",
    region: "us-east-1",
}

this.s3 = new S3(config);
```

then to get the signed url to then be used to display an image:

```
const min = expireMin ? expireMin : 20;

const expires = 60 * min; // Expires in 20 minutes.

const params = {
    Bucket: "MyBucket",
    Key: key,
    Expires: expires,
};

const signedUrl = await this.s3.getSignedUrlPromise("getObject", params);

return signedUrl;
```

The url appears to get signed just fine and returns, however, whenever I try and use the url, I get a 400 Bad Request.

https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image-guid/thumbnail.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=...&Expires=...&Signature=...&x-amz-security-token=...

On my local environment, I load the S3 service using an IAM User using an AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and it works no problem. So the image is there and works correctly in this scenario. But doing it with my EC2 instance with an IAM Role attached to it, it doesn't.

If I tried to GET the url with Postman, it returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidToken</Code>
    <Message>The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.</Message>
    <Token-0>...</Token-0>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
    <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was manually loading the credentials in manually when the service was starting up, where I didn't need to do this at all with the aws sdk. It was then messing up the signing process. Once I removed the manual credential assignment it resolved the issue.